# Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string

Tags: curl, php-curl, razorpay

```
<?php

$url = "https://api.razorpay.com/v1/contacts/cont_00000000000001";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PATCH, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
   "Content-Type: application/json",
   "Authorization: Basic cnpwXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0E",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = <<<DATA
{
  "name": "Tester",
  "email": "test@example.com",
  "contact": "9876543210",
  "type": "self",
  "reference_id": "Contact ID 12345",
  "notes": {
    "notes_key_1":"Tea, Earl Grey, Hot",
    "notes_key_2":"Tea, Earl Grey… decaf."
  }
}
DATA;

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);

?>
```

when I'm trying to execute this code I'm getting this error

**Warning**: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_PATCH - assumed 'CURLOPT_PATCH' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\payout_curl\update_contact.php on line 7

**Warning**: curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\payout_curl\update_contact.php on line 7
string(155) "{"error":{"code":"BAD_REQUEST_ERROR","description":"The requested URL was not found on the server.","source":null,"step":null,"reason":null,"metadata":{}}}"

why I'm getting this

Answer (score 0):

Hello try this way ...

```
<?php
    
    $url = "https://api.razorpay.com/v1/contacts/";
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    
    $headers = array(
       "Content-Type: application/json",
       "Authorization: Basic cnpwXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0E",
    );
    
    /* method 1 auth
    $headers = array(
      'Content-Type:application/json',
      'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("user:password") // <--- youruser:yourpass
    );*/
    
    /* method 2 auth 
    $login = "youruser";
    $password = "yourpass";
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$login:$password");*/
    

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    
    $data = array(
      'name' => 'Tester',
      'email' => 'test@example.com',
      'contact' => '9876543210',
      'type' => 'self',
      'reference_id' => 'Contact ID 12345',
      'notes' => array(
        'notes_key_1' => 'Tea, Earl Grey, Hot',
        'notes_key_2' => 'Tea, Earl Grey… decaf.'
      )
    );
    
    $data = http_build_query($data);
    
    /* http_build_query output: name=Tester&email=test@example.com&contact=9876543210&type=self.... */
    /* and use urlencode to have the @ and spaces posted corectly .. */
    
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode($data));
    
    //for debug only!
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    var_dump($resp);
    
?>
```

And make sure you have php_curl.dll module in your php.ini enabled ...

Noticed if extension=php_curl.dll is commented in C:\xampp\bin\php\php.XXX\php.ini or C:\xampp\bin\apache\ApacheXXXX\bin\php.ini.

You must uncommenting the line ;extension=php_curl.dll in C:\xampp\bin\php\php.XXX\php.ini or C:\xampp\bin\apache\ApacheXXXX\bin\php.ini fixed the issue.

And

> curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PATCH, true); not exist in curl library ..
>
> Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_PATCH - assumed 'CURLOPT_PATCH'

Use for make a POST request white custom arguments:

> curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST')

> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

Use for make a GET request white custom arguments:

> curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET')

Comment: yes I have enabled the file you said but still i'm facing the same problem

Comment: try the above code has been modified and should work now